# Deserializing JSON containing invalid class identifiers

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

In Java, using Jackson, I want to deserialize JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
  "123_ABC": {
    "XYZ": 768,
    "123_DATA": {
      "123_DEF": "",
      "123_ACT": "ZAC",
      "123_PAG": {
        "123_PAG_A": 1,
        "123_PAG_B": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You all know that identifiers starting with a number are invalid in Java (and every programming language I ever heard of.)

I already know how to use @JsonProperty to translate field names, but handling class names is outside my knowledge.

If I define classes corresponding to the structure of the JSON, but with valid class names, is there a way to use Jackson annotations to map the invalid class id in the JSON to my valid class names?

Answer (score 0):

I think `@JsonProperty` should be good to deserialize this.

Let's create a wrapper class that will have `123_ABC` as a property of class `ValidClass`.

```
class Wrapper {

    @JsonProperty("123_ABC")
    private ValidClass validName;
}
```

Now, when you serialize, it will create JSON like this (or can be deserialized using that)

```
{ "123_ABC":{ //PROPERTIES OF ValidClass HERE } }
```

Similarly, you can have different properties in further inner classes.

In case if you to support `123_ABC` only for deserialization and serialize with correct field names, you can do like this

```
@JsonAlias("123_ABC")
private ValidClass validName;
```

it will serialize to following.

```
{"validName": {//properties}}
```

but deserialization can be done using both

```
{"validName": {//properties}}
{"123_ABC": {//properties}}
```

In case, if keys keep changing, I would suggest to deserialize them in Map.